# Upload current date and time into mysql

Tags: android

I need to post current time and date into database using android.I have tried with volley but shows NULL pointer exception in Requestqueue. if there is any other method to post please help me out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView time1,date1;
public static final String REGISTER_URL_DATE = 
"http://192.168.0.102/date.php";

public static String KEY_DATE="date",KEY_TIME="time",date,time;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    time1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    date1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    DateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     date=dfDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    DateFormat dfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
     time = dfTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
  time1.setText(time);
    date1.setText(date);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL_DATE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            params.put(KEY_TIME,time);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Comment: post your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know android but I would suggest you to add current date and time from your backend rather than frontend i.e. through app. You can use GetDate() in your insert query to save current date and time.

```
insert into testTable values('1565071',GETDATE())
```

I am suggesting this way as it would reduce hussel from android as well as iOS while sending date in required format.

M using My SQL Server 2008. hope it helps.